# High Voltage Transformer - effect of increasing frequency

Tags: power-supply, high-voltage, high-frequency

I have a 110 V to 15 kV transformer (60 Hz) which I'm using for high voltage experiments.

I need to increase the frequency of the input / output power to be in the kHz or MHz range. Can you tell me what would the effect be on the transformer? Would it burn out quickly or blow up?

Cheers

Comment: The size of magnetic core required in the transformer varies decreases with increasing frequency. Generally you can increase the frequency with the same transformer, although the skin effect means less efficient usage of conductors so less ampacity.

Comment: x2 in frequency is generally OK, not much hit to efficiency, and 2x volts per turn is worthwhile. x10 in frequency generally fatal to efficiency, can't use remotely near to rated power due to core heating, can't use theoretical x10 in volts per turn as insulation is not up to it.

Answer (score 5):

The core is probably made from silicon steel laminates. These are about 1mm thick and insulated from each other. Their surfaces are electrically insulated to prevent the whole of the core being a gigantic shorted turn. As frequency increases, those laminations need to get thinner proportional with frequency or each laminate will start to circulate unacceptably-high induced eddy currents.

This basically means that your transformer becomes useless above a few hundred hertz.